# Partial derivative of the stress tensor

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In my notes it is written that

$$\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j}$$

is equivalent to $\nabla\cdot{\boldsymbol \sigma}$ but I'm slightly confused how this is true since the stress tensor $\boldsymbol\sigma$ is a rank 2 tensor and hence a matrix. How is the divergence of a matrix then a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at it this way, you have $\nabla= (\partial_{x_1},\partial_{x_2},\partial_{x_3})$, and $\sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} \\
\sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} & \sigma_{23} \\
\sigma_{31} & \sigma_{32} & \sigma_{33} \end{array} \right)$.

Then by dot product they mean you have the vector:
$$(\sum_{j=1}^3 \partial_{x_j}\sigma_{1j},\sum_{j=1}^3 \partial_{x_j}\sigma_{2j},\sum_{j=1}^3 \partial_{x_j}\sigma_{3j})$$

I.e, it's a dot product of nabla with the rows of the matrix.

P.S
They are using Einstein summation convention.

Comment: Hi sorry, shouldn't it be $\partial_{x_j}\sigma_{j1}$ etc.? And why is the divergence a vector rather than a scalar?

Comment: It seems so, yes; so you need to replace in your OP $\frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j}$ to $\frac{\partial \sigma_{ji}}{\partial x_j}$; and this is the $i$th term of the vector. Are you taking a course in Continuum mechanics or Hydrodynamics? The best books that I am reading are by Sedov and Batchelor.